# Initialize bean while project deployment spring

Tags: spring, javabeans

I was asked in one of interview that how we can initialize bean while project deployment in Spring ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

- Your bean can implement [InitializingBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html) interface and initialization work can be done inside afterPropertiesSet() method
- You can just add a method in a bean class and annotate it with @PostConstruct
- You can add method in a bean class and mark it as an init method. Using xml config the bean definition would look like this:

  ```
  <beans>
      <bean id="myBean" class="..." init-method="init"/>
  </beans>
  ```

  And using Java config like this:

  ```
  @Bean(initMethod="init")
  public MyBean myBean() {
      return new MyBean();
  }
  ```
- You can also implement your own [BeanPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) and provide implementation in postProcessAfterInitialization or postProcessBeforeInitialization methods.

**One caveat:** all this initialization logic is a part of bean lifecycle, which doesn't mean that it will be invoked during the project deployment. 
However if bean is a singleton bean then by default it is created during the spring context start up. I guess it is what you mean by project deployment.